# .next() doesn't working within .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bootstrap-tooltip plugin to display tooltips.
And my HTML is like this:

```
<a href="#" data-role="tooltip" title="">actions</a>
<div class="user-actions">
    <a class="icon" href="/edit">
        <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="icon" href="/delete">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-role=tooltip]').tooltip({
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        trigger: 'click'
    });

    $('a[data-role=tooltip]').each(function(){
        var content = this.next().html()
        this.attr('title', content);
    });
});
```

What I want my script to do is to loop through every `<a data-role='tooltip' title=''>` selector, then find immediately following selector, get its html and put it as a value of `title` attribute.

BUT

it just doesn't work.
The console error says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'next'
```

What I did wrong? And how I can make it work?

Comment: `this` is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is not a jQuery object. It's a DOM element. You'd do this instead:

```
$('a[data-role=tooltip]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).next().html());
});
```

---

Though this is better:

```
$('a[data-role=tooltip]').attr("title", function() {
    return $(this).next().html();
});
```

...since it only requires that you call `.attr()` once.

Comment: multiple calls to `$()` should be avoided - better to call it once, then cache the result and use that

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the raw dom element - and needs to be wrapped first before using jquery methods on it.

```
$('a[data-role=tooltip]').each(function(){
    // cache the jquery object
    var $this = $(this);
    var content = $this.next().html()
    $this.attr('title', content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just wrap it:

`$(this)` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. **More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.**

So `this` refers to an `HTMLElement` object (or a subclass of `HTMLElement`, as you're seeing in your logged exception). You'll need to wrap it like `$(this)` before being able to call jQuery methods on it.